# How to not save history?

Tags: android, html

When i call location.replace in webview.
My browser save history.

If i call following command:

```
1. location.href='a.html';
2. location.replace('a.html?loc=1');
3. location.replace('a.html?loc=2');
4. history.back();
```

Browser move to step2.

I Think,

This command have to move step1.

Have I misunderstood?

Comment: have you tried location.assign(url) instead or using assign for the first command, maybe the href='a.html' is not registered in the history?

Comment: What happens if you use history.back two times ?